# Are the last two primaries and caucuses won by Hillary Clinton under investigation for major voting irregularities?

Tags: united-states, politics

There's an image floating around Facebook lately. I can't seem to verify it.

[image: Clinton elections under investigation]

The text reads:

> I won two out of the last ten primaries and caucuses.
>
> Both are under investigation for major election irregularities.

I could only find [someone repeating it word for word](https://m.facebook.com/foxnashville/posts/10154113422952290), or perhaps he's the originator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, they are under investigation for irregularities. I can't find any relation to Mrs Clinton though.

There are two separate investigations regarding the New York City (New York) Board of Elections.<sup>1, 2, 3</sup>

The DOJ is investigating Maricopa County (Arizona) regarding its reduction in polling places.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1. [ABC News: NYC Primary Voter Complaints Draw Investigations, Suspension](http://abcnews.go.com/US/wireStory/nyc-primary-voter-complaints-draw-investigations-suspension-38619351)</sup>

<sup>2. [Statement From A.G. Schneiderman On Voting Issues During New York’s Primary Election](http://www.ag.ny.gov/press-release/statement-ag-schneiderman-voting-issues-during-new-york%E2%80%99s-primary-election)</sup>

<sup>3. [New York City Comptroller's Statement](http://comptroller.nyc.gov/newsroom/amid-widespread-reports-of-voter-disenfranchisement-and-polling-problems-comptroller-stringer-announces-audit-of-board-of-elections/)</sup>

<sup>4. [U.S. Department of Justice Letter to Maricopa County Recorder](http://archive.azcentral.com/persistent/icimages/news/DOJ%20Letter%20to%20Maricopa.pdf)</sup>